# Pass Arraylist of objects in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist

I am trying to send an array list of objects in another activity. I have checked many articles on this topic and i am using parcelable but i am stuck at point where i cannot send the object.I have tried many things.This is the thing i am trying.

```
public class ParcalableForm implements Parcelable {

private ArrayList<form> from;


public ParcalableForm (ArrayList<form> choices) {
    this.from = choices;
}

public ParcalableForm (Parcel parcel) {
    this.from = parcel.readArrayList(null);
}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

// Required method to write to Parcel
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(from);
}

// Method to recreate a Question from a Parcel
public static Creator<ParcalableForm> CREATOR = new Creator<ParcalableForm>() {

    @Override
    public ParcalableForm createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ParcalableForm(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ParcalableForm[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcalableForm[size];
    }

};
```

}

This is the parcelable class that implements Parcelable.I am trying to send Arraylist of form to another activity.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(UserPage.this,Form.class);

  Bundle extras = new Bundle();
  System.out.println("I found a form :- ");
  ParcalableForm p=new ParcalableForm(f1.attr);
  i.putExtra("geopoints", p);
  startActivity(i);
```

This is the class which is sending the object to the other activity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
ParcalableForm po =  new ParcalableForm(extras.getParcelableArrayList("geopoints"));
```

This is the part where i don't know how to get the object/Arraylist.I have tried many methods but no luck.Any ideas?

Comment: I guess that you have a custom form class. That class must implement Parcelable too.

Comment: Yes i have done that too..Doesnt work

Comment: 1. Make Form implement parcelable, 2. get rid of `ParcalableForm` class. 3. use `put/getParcelableArrayListExtra` on the intent to pass the array list. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

Pass Data to anther activity

```
 ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
//fill your list with animals here

i.putExtra("animals", animals);
```

Receiving this data

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = (ArrayList<Animal>) getIntent()
                        .getSerializableExtra("animals");
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to pass `ArrayList<Form>`, then use [getParcelableArrayListExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)) for this.
Generally, follow these steps :

- Make your `Form` class properly [implement Parcelable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/2358786)
- In activity sending intent :

  `// ArrayList<Form> myList - data to send;
  intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("geopoints", myList);`
- In receiving activity :

  `ArrayList<Form> myReceivedList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("geopoints");`

And don't forget null/sanity checks.

Hope that helps

Comment: I get an error `Cannot cast from ArrayList<Parcelable> to ArrayList<Location>`