# SQLite get all data and pass it to an Adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I have this code which gets some data from a database

```
  public List<Objects> getAllObjects() {
        List<Objects> Objectslist = new ArrayList<Objects>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OBJECTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Objects object = new Objects();
                object.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                object.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                object.setUrl(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                Objectslist.add(object);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

In my MainActivity, I am getting it like this

```
  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                List<Objects> Objects = db.getAllObjects();
                DBadapter adapter = new DBadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, Objects);
```

I am getting an error in my DBadatper, here

```
 public DBadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Objects> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);//error here
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext =context;
        System.out.println("entering adapter");
    }
```

the error is: `Cannot Resolve method..`
I guess because of the List object, but how to fix that?

adapter class

```
public class DBadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Listitem> {
    private static Uri[] mUrls = null;
    private static String[] strUrls = null;
    private String[] mNames = null;
    private Cursor cc = null;
    private Context mcontext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private List<?> listitems;
    public DBadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Objects> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext =context;
        this.listitems = listitem;
        System.out.println("entering adapter");
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("entering adapter1");

        View row = convertView;
        final  ViewHolder holder;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Listitem item = getItem(position);
        System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
        System.out.println(item.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mcontext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
        Picasso.
                with(mcontext).
                load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");
                Intent intnt  =new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
                intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //Bitmap imageID=holder.imageView;
                //intnt.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
                mcontext.startActivity(intnt)  ; //This line raises error


                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "intent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }


}
```

Objects.java

```
public class Objects(){
private int id;
private String name;
private String url;

public Objects ( String name, String url)
{
this.name = name;
this.url=url;
}
public Objects()
{
}
public int getId() { return id; }

public String getName() { return name;}
public String getUrl() { return url;}
}
```

Comment: What does the stack trace exactly say?

Comment: @chx101 i cant run the app because I am getting error here `super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);` the error is `Cannot resolve method super(android.content.Context,int,java.util.list<com.app.www.app.Objects>)`

Comment: What class does `DBadapter` extend? Make sure you have required imports.

Comment: @chx101 it extends SQLiteOpenHelper and I add all the imports required

Comment: Please take a look at the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructors. The constructor you are calling doesn't exist. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Here's a tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @chx101 I am already reading this tutorial, and there is not constructor for `SQLiteOpenHelper` beside my question is in the adapter not in sqlite. I am passing a list in the adapter however I am getting error . is it correct how I am passing the List object?

Comment: @Moudiz Upvote, question is clear an no downvote needed.

Comment: @Milad thank you man, can you help me in my question?

Comment: I'm trying to do so ;)

Comment: Are you following that tutorial or do you mind posting your whole code here (the adapter class)?

Comment: @chx101 in that site they are just explaining about sqlite , what I am trying to do is pass those data to adapter . anyway check my edit

Comment: @chx101 still error exists, maybe you right I am extending arrayadapter however I am using list. is it possible it is the problem ?

Comment: Just use the two argument constructor. Change `super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);` to `super(content, 0);` Override the other functions, `getCount()`, `getItem()`, etc

Comment: @chx101 do you a good tutorial on how to diplay sqlite data into a list customized adapter

Comment: `public List<Objects> getAllObjects()` do not return a `List`, simply return a `Cursor` instead and pass it to `SimpleCursorAdapter` that is all... just compare [this](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) with your (not working yet) code

Comment: @pskink the link had a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, I am working on custom, do you have an example ?

Comment: i sent you a link,  it is a custom adapter

Comment: @pskink in the link you provided they mentioned simplecursoradapter, can you please point where custom adapter

Comment: you can customize SimpleCursorAdapter like in my link,  what is not clear?

Comment: @Moudiz Why do you need to super. What if you remove it?

Comment: @LayLeangsros I am used to use super, I am not sure but ill get an error if I remove it.

Comment: take a look  at the link i posted: they show two fields per one row like you,  but they use 1/5 lines of code compared to your solution

Comment: @pskink this is your [link](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) correct ? there is no custom adapter, I want to use picasso , there is simpleadapter only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you update your classes like the following:

Objects.java:

```
public class Objects {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public Objects() {
    }

    public Objects(int id, String name, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

DBAdapter.java:

```
public class DBAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Objects> {
    private static Uri[] mUrls = null;
    private static String[] strUrls = null;
    private String[] mNames = null;
    private Cursor cc = null;
    private Context mcontext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private List<?> listitems;

    public DBAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Objects> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.listitems = listitem;
        System.out.println("entering adapter");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("entering adapter1");

        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Objects item = getItem(position);
        System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
        System.out.println(item.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mcontext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
        Picasso.
                with(mcontext).
                load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");
                Intent intnt = new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
                intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //Bitmap imageID=holder.imageView;
                //intnt.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
                mcontext.startActivity(intnt); 


                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "intent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tomorrow morning OK? I am busy now

Comment: yes no problem when i ask it ill post it here .. thanks

Comment: hi man can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843875/passing-arraylist-to-asnother-activity-cannot-resolve-putextra?

Comment: @Moudiz I have not tried sending arraylist to other activity yet, tomorrow if your issue is not fixed and if I have free time, I will check for you :). IMO you can read some links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619027/pass-arraylist-of-objects-in-another-activity

Comment: hi man I did read the links , they are all using parcelable but the problem is with intent. It needs to start activity. and i only to need to pass it to another activity, not to start a new activity.

Comment: @Moudiz, IMO, `pass to another activity` = `start a new activity`

Comment: i posted a question here explaining detailed my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866314/when-cicked-on-grid-view-how-to-send-arralistposition-to-another-actvity

Comment: I have answered, however, why don't you want to go to another activity? If so, where does the arraylist will come to and how to process it in the second activity?

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at the difference between what have you done and what you need to do.

```
public class DBadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Objects> {

    List<Object> modelItems = null;
    Context context;    
    public Resources res;


    public DBadapter (Context context,List<Object> resource) {
        super(context,R.layout.grid_item_layout,resource);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.modelItems = resource;             
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: what should i send from main activity `DBadapter adapter = new DBadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, Objects);`

Comment: DBadapter adapter = new DBadapter(getApplicationContext(), Objects);

Comment: I got error on objects item = getItem(position); incomaptible types required app.objects found java.lang.object

Comment: Are you talking about this line  :  Listitem item = getItem(position); ?

Comment: yes correct. I posted the error in my above comment

Comment: Please check the return type of your object and getitem. Both should have same return type

Comment: please can you explain where ? class objects its `public int getId() { return id;` where I should check also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95512/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-moudiz).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// Changed Listitem to Objects
public class DBadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Objects> {
    private static Uri[] mUrls = null;
    private static String[] strUrls = null;
    private String[] mNames = null;
    private Cursor cc = null;
    private Context mcontext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private List<?> listitems;
    public DBadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Objects> listitem) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, listitem);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mcontext =context;
        this.listitems = listitem;
        System.out.println("entering adapter");
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("entering adapter1");

        View row = convertView;
        final  ViewHolder holder;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        // Added (ListItem) cast
        Listitem item = (Listitem) getItem(position); // here you should define your getItem(int) function in Objects class
        System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
        System.out.println(item.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mcontext).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
        Picasso.
                with(mcontext).
                load(item.getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .noFade()
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");
                Intent intnt  =new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
                intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //Bitmap imageID=holder.imageView;
                //intnt.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
                mcontext.startActivity(intnt)  ; //This line raises error


                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "intent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView imageView;
    }


}
```

Comment: ok ill test it but can you please explain why you change it to Object ? my setter/getter is Objects

Comment: this code in my maint activity what should I replace with `objects`      because I am getting error           DBadapter adapter = new DBadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, Objects);

Comment: I tried this but didnt work 
        Listitem item = (Listitem) getItem(object.getId()); what should I add ?

Comment: can you post your `Objects` class?

Comment: I dont have acess to the laptop, but its setter and getter , setId and getId. the error on the android studio said : expected listobject something like that