# Pass an int array to another activity

Tags: java, android, arrays

I found other questions in this website that are similar to mine; I tried their sugestions but I keep getting the NullPointExceptionError as below:

" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int[] android.os.Bundle.getIntArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

This is what I have so far:

Activity of the original array:

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putIntArray("PTArray", PTFindings);
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
intent.putExtra("PTArray", PTFindings);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity that receives this array:

```
int[] PTData = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("PTArray");
Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
PTData = myBundle.getIntArray("PTArray");
```

*** Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: IMHO, you can refer to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866314/when-clicked-on-grid-view-how-to-send-arralistposition-to-another-actvity/33866720#33866720 to see its logic about passing arraylist to another activity.

Comment: @BNK You can pass Integer Arrays directly, without the need of a class implementing Parcelable

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau thanks for your info, I have not tested it yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this as your original:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PTArray", PTFindings);
startActivity(intent);
```

and this for receive :

```
Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int[] PTData = myBundle.getIntArray("PTArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an Intent which is passed to the new Activity. Try changing

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ComponentInfo.class);
```

Then the Intent should be passed to the receiving class.

Another point is, in your code, you do not pass the Bundle to the Intent. So `getIntent().getExtras();` will actually return `null` in your Code, thus `myBundle.getIntArray` resulting in NPE. So when you want to access a Bundle in your next Activity, don't forget to call

```
intent.putExtra(myBundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass your `myBundle` or the target activity to the intent, try with this:

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putIntArray("PTArray", PTFindings);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ComponentInfo.class);
intent.putExtra("PTArray", PTFindings);
intent.putExtra(myBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```